# Pronunciation: /ɪ/ becomes /ə/ in "William" or "Wilkinson"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology, phonetics

I sometimes hear words like "Willam" or "Wilkinson" pronounced like /'wəl-jəm/ or /'wəɫ̩-kən-sən/, rather than /'wɪɫ̩-jəm/ or /'wɪɫ̩-kən-sən/. In other words, the /wɪɫ̩/ cluster is sometimes swapped with /wəl/. It seems to me like the former word William is especially affected by such coarticulation(?) when it's following or followed by another word, say Sherwin-Williams or William Shakespeare in a bit rapid speech.

Am I just getting it wrong as a non-native speaker? Or is there any phonological/linguistic background on this?

Comment: Where are you?  I am in the US, and have not noticed this.

Comment: I'm not in the US because I'm a non-native English learner.

Comment: In English, vowels often do strange things before /l/. This one isn't listed in Wikipedia's page [English language vowel changes before historic l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/l/#:~:text=The%20hull%E2%80%93hole%20merger%20is,are%20homophones%20as%20%5Bh%C9%94%CA%8A%5D.), but some speakers might have this merger.

Comment: As you pointed out I think it may be related to velarized l.
By the way you can hear /'wəl-jəm/ here, for instance:
https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/william
Or at 52:07 "...a young gentlemen would do wich is to go to the College of /'wəl-jəm/ and Mary..."
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0v_xOAWY6_I

Comment: I hear /ɪ/ in the Lexico link. I also hear it in the video clip but when I listen closely I think I can detect more of a schwa there but native speakers “know” it’s supposed to be the /ɪ/ phoneme and so they hear it that way.

Comment: 1) It could be a regional accent (like Geordie or Cornwall) 2) the schwa -never- appears in a stressed syllable - what vowel that is not a schwa is it closest to in this atypical pronunciation? Maybe you mean ['ʌ'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_unrounded_vowel) or ['ɛ'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_central_unrounded_vowel)? [Visit this vowel chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel) and listen to them and see which one corresponds to what you think you hear. 3) I don't hear it, it sounds closest to 'ɪ' to me (GenAmE).

Comment: Oh you hear /ɪ/ in the lexico link.
Perhaps I can say it sounds to me like /'wʊɫ̩-jəm/.Wull-yum.Actually Webster says "will" is pronounced /wəl/ in its weak form.
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will

I think it sounds a bit different from /ɪ/ in wit, wish or which, maybe because I'm not used to English vowels though.

Comment: @Mitch; the vowel schwa never appears in a stressed syllable by definition. But in many dialects of British English, the vowel /ɜː/ in nurse is distinguished from schwa only by length and stress, and in many dialects of American English, the vowel /ʌ/ in strut is distinguished from schwa only by stress. So saying that schwa never appears in a stressed syllable is beside the point here.

Comment: i should've put it clearer, but I could say the schwa in /wəl/ would be sort of an archiphoneme representing a mixture of /ə/ and /ʊ/.To me, it sounds similar to /ʊ/ in full/fʊl/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There *is* actually a phonological change in some American English accents where General American /ɪ/ is moving towards [ə]. This change is part of the [Northern Cities Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inland_Northern_American_English#Backing_or_lowering_of_/%C9%AA/), which has been happening in and around cities in the Great Lakes region since the 1930s or so.

Here's a clip of [news anchor Jeff Russo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNU_qV2BNmQ) pronouncing "Williamsville" with a very schwa-like vowel in the first syllable. Russo is originally from Rochester, NY, a city where the accent is considered a [canonical example](https://www.rochester.edu/pr/Review/V68N1/inrev07.html) of this vowel shift.

There are many American accents unaffected by this change, but it's possible that *some* of the instances you've observed are the result of the Northern Cities shift.

Comment: Also, postvocalic /l/ in English is velarized ("dark"), and that tends to move front vowels back; I've even heard "Wooliam" with a high back rounded lax vowel instead of high front unrounded vowel. Skipping the central vowel completely.

Comment: I checked out the video and that's what I meant.I think the merger frequently occurs in words containing "will", such as "willfully" or "willpower".This also occurs in we'll(though its IPA is /wil/).According to Webster and CMU, the word "will" is surely pronounced /wəl/
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will
https://linguistics.berkeley.edu/~kjohnson/English_Phonetics/small_pronouncing_dictionary.html

 /wəl/
9:40 ...for those who willfully...
10:00 ... powers escalates we'll be...
11:32 ... high impact deliberate willful or...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-OxIzDOym0

Comment: Let me ask another question if possible.
I can pronounce /'wɪɫ̩-jəm/ slowly, but when I try to say it in regular speed, it's getting very hard and I'll end up with something similar to /'wəɫ̩-jəm/(or /'wʊɫ̩-jəm/), /'wɪ:-jəm/(where the /ɪ:/ is not /i/.It's just a longer edition of kit/kɪt/ vowel.) or /'wɪl-jəm/(where /l/ is light l) .I think it's because my tongue tip doesn't touch the alveolar ridge when I pronounce dark l/ɫ̩/.
Is /'wɪɫ̩-jəm/, William with dark l, even possible in a fast daily speech?
I can pronounce million, billion or zillion, but I just can't William.

Comment: Interesting question! To answer it well we'd need an imaging study to determine exact tongue positions, but based on articulatory phonetics, I'd say [yes, mostly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oODegeP7yrU).

The "mostly" part is because speakers who use an on-target /ɪ/ would produce a less velarized [ɫ] here than they would after a back vowel as in the word "fall." In "William" the sequence [ɪɫj] requires the tongue body to go from front to back to front again very quickly, which is physically difficult, so the middle one is likely to be less accurate as rate of speech increases.

Comment: @Aralcar >a less velarized [ɫ] here than they would after a back vowel as in the word "fall."
That is probably the exact answer I wanted.
I personally find it easier to make the sound you pointed out when I try to mimic "light l" with the tongue tip off the alveolar ridge.That way I can make "light-or-nuh l" sound, which would be caused somewhere in the middle of velar and palatal(lighter than usual /ɫ̩/), and lighter than "fall" or "full" yet darker than "like" or "laughter ".
By the way some people seem to pronounce million as /mɪʎən/.

Comment: This may be redundant, but in the original video above, both Jeff and the narrator pronounce "will" or "williams" notably schwa-ish, i.e. with /wəɫ̩/ while they pronounce other words with /ɪ/ just as it is.So I guess there may be some special rule for words containing "will".
Sorry for posting so many.